# Access to cumulocity maven repository

Tags: java, cumulocity

I would like to develop for cumulocity and I wanted to try the demos from bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-clients-java). Unfortunatelly, in order to run these, I need access to the Cumulocity Maven repository.

I also need access for writing new code as well.

Where can I find the relevant informations (Credentials/addresses)?

Comment: In their README it says you need to visit this page: https://www.softwareag.cloud/site/product/cumulocity-iot.html#/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [README.md](https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-clients-java/src/default/README.md) please configure the Cumulocity repositories for your maven. Released dependencies to build the cumulocity-clients-java repo are available there without specific access permissions.

Make sure your build only refereces released cumulocity dependencies, not snapshots. You can easily distinguish them by the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix to their versions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have downloaded a release branch (r1004.4.0) but it still refernced some SNAPSHOT versions. I have run `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1004.4.0` and now when I run `mvn clean install` I have the following error `Could not find artifact com.nsn.cumulocity.dependencies.osgi:svenson:jar:1.5.8-1004.4.0 in cumulocity-maven-repo (http://resources.cumulocity.com/maven/repository)`. The good news is that some jars (core-model) were downloaded.

Comment: Do you specifically require such new versions? Otherwise I would recommend going with the platform release you are targeting or the latest generally available release, which is 10.4.0.0 at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. It now compiles. Last question: Is it compatible with java 11?